# Should 'traverse' word only be used to describe/tell the route to a place or can be used for a process or procedure even?

Tags: word-usage

Like 'you will have to traverse through all these steps again'.

Comment: It's probably OK, but [you don't want 'through'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=traverse+all%2Ctraverse+through+all&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "traverse" should only be used to indicate traveling over or through something, often over a specific kind of terrain. It can, however, be used in metaphors that express a different concept by invoking an image similar to traveling over a specific kind of terrain or traveling through a given location.

The example sentence is not a correct usage. Here are some correct usage examples:

"To reach Mount Doom, Frodo and his companion had to traverse the treacherous paths of the Dead Marshes." This is correct because the travelers are traveling *through* the Dead Marshes.

"Traversing the complex code base is daunting, but this map makes it more manageable." Here, "traverse" is used to support a metaphor. You don't actually traverse through a code base, but trying to make sense of the code behind a complex application can oftentimes resemble a journey of sorts. This sentence invokes that metaphor and then uses "traverse" to indicate traveling *through* the application's code.

A better phrasing of the example sentence would be, "You will have to *repeat* all these steps again."

Comment: In the field of serious climbing, "traverse" is used to specify a technique or maneuver in which you progress horizontally (sideways) versus vertically - so in that specific use-case you will hear someone say:
"What is she doing now?"
"Oh, she's traversing - that route has a bee's nest on the main approach and she's being really careful - she's allergic!"

Comment: I don't entirely agree with the phrasing suggestion given, if only because there is a difference in focus: Saying "You will have to *traverse* all these steps again" emphasizes each individual traversal, whereas "You will have to *repeat* all these steps again" emphasizes the repetition of the entire procedure (made up of "all these steps") as a whole. Minor nitpick, so don't mind me.

Comment: As @GerardFalla says, traverse is horizontal progress, or a perhaps a circumlocution. *Steps*, on the other hand, are a vertical metaphor for progress. So this doesn't work because it is a mixed metaphor. You can traverse a lot of different things, but steps aren't one of them.